# Откуда появляютя неизвестные поля cookies?

Tags: cookie, https, firefox

Изучаю ресурс https://sbermarket.ru. Во вкладке "Сеть" инструментов веб-разработчика Firefox смотрю на запросы, которые отправляются на сервер  и приходят с него.

Для того, чтобы у меня в куки появилось какое-либо новое поле, сервер должен сообщить об этом браузеру через "set-cookie". Проблема в том, что у меня в куки-запросе появляются новые поля без предварительного куки-ответа сервера с названиями этих полей.

Откуда берутся новые поля куки? Как их обнаружить?

P.S.: откуда появляются самые первые куки (*_808db7ba1248*, *_Instamart_session*, *city_info*, *external_analytics_anonymous_id*) мне понятно, а вот уже следующие откуда берутся последующие (например: *_pk_id.6.3ec0*, *_pk_ses.6.3ec0*, *_sa*) мне уже не ясно.

Comment: скорее всего на фронте еще куки через скрипт ставятся

Comment: Там в исходниках есть файлы, где куки ставятся

Comment: @PavelNazarian, я посмотрел присылаемые скрипты до места появления куки с названием *_pk_id.6.3ec0*, но нигде не нашел совпадения, т.е. нигде не указано такого имени. Может я не там ищу. Что вы имеете в виду под исходниками?